# Authentication in feathersjs / angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, feathersjs

I have a typical web app with a login form and I'm trying to use feathersjs for the backend to authenticate the user over rest. I am using angular 4 for the front end.

Front end auth service in Angular 4:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private BASE_URL: string = 'http://localhost:3030';
  private headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  login(user): Promise<any> {
    let url: string = `${this.BASE_URL}/authentication`;
    return this.http.post(url, user, {headers: this.headers}).toPromise();
  }
}
```

config/default.json in back-end:

```
"authentication": {
    "secret": "my-secret",
    "strategies": [
      "jwt",
      "local"
    ],
    "path": "/authentication",
    "service": "users",
    "jwt": {
      "header": {
        "typ": "access"
      },
      "audience": "https://yourdomain.com",
      "subject": "anonymous",
      "issuer": "feathers",
      "algorithm": "HS256",
      "expiresIn": "1d"
    },
    "local": {
      "entity": "teams",
      "usernameField": "email",
      "passwordField": "password"
    }
  }
```

authentication.js in back-end

```
const authentication = require('feathers-authentication');
const jwt = require('feathers-authentication-jwt');
const local = require('feathers-authentication-local');


module.exports = function () {
  const app = this;
  const config = app.get('authentication');

  // Set up authentication with the secret
  app.configure(authentication(config));
  app.configure(jwt());
  app.configure(local());

  app.service('authentication').hooks({
    before: {
      create: [
        authentication.hooks.authenticate(config.strategies)
      ],
      remove: [
        authentication.hooks.authenticate('jwt')
      ]
    }
  });
};
```

With the above I'm getting 404 for the /authentication end point. Do I have to create the authentication end-point manually or does featherjs create it for me? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Why is Angular mentioned at all? The question is specific to back end and can likely be debugged and replicated with Postman or so. Yes, `/authentication` should work this way. Double check if there are no errors from auth plugin in Node console. Consider providing http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (e.g. a repo), because Feathers package versions matter.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to include the  "strategy" in the request body.

```
{
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "password": "1234",
  "strategy": "local"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate client before you can make request. Following is the example to do so:

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const feathers = require('@feathersjs/client');
const socketio = require('@feathersjs/socketio-client');
const authentication = require('@feathersjs/authentication-client');
const LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage;

    const client = feathers();
        const socket = io('http://localhost:3030');

        const localStorage = new LocalStorage('./storage');
        client.configure(socketio(socket));
        client.configure(authentication({storage: localStorage}));

        client
            .authenticate(['jwt', 'local']).then(() => {
            console.log("Auto authenticated");
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            client
                .authenticate({
                    strategy: 'local', email: "feathers@example.com",
                    password: "secret"
                }).then(() => {
                console.log("Authenticated using Email");
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log('Unable to authenticate to server');
                process.exit(1);
            });
        });
        client.on('authenticated', (login) => {
            console.log('Authenticated to server', login);
            client.service('task').create({
                text: 'A message from a REST client'
            }).then(() => {
                console.log("Task created");
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log("error", error);
            });
        });
```